# ¿Cómo convertir un valor numérico en una cadena jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

```
  function validacion_semestre_materia() {
   var id_gestion = $('#valges').val();
   var id_materia =  $('#txtmateria').val();
   var id_dia = $('#txtdia').val();
   var id_horario = $('#txthora').val();
   var id_semestre =  $('#semestre').val();
   var id_carrera =  $('#txtcarrera').val();
   $.post("includes/masevalidoresAjax.php", 
         {
           id_gestion: id_gestion, 
           id_materia: id_materia, 
           id_dia: id_dia,  
           id_horario: id_horario, 
           id_semestre:  id_semestre , 
           id_carrera: id_carrera
          }, function (data) {    
             $('#materiasemestre').val(data);
    });   
}
```

Comment: Cual valor quieres convertir?

Comment: ya lo resolvi mi respuesta tenia trabajar en la base datos utilize lpad char en la base de datos cuando utilizo post solo admite valores numericos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar JavaScript, solamente en la variable que tengas de tipo numérico, aplica el método toString, por ejemplo:

```js
var edad = 20;
edad = edad.toString();
```